# Simple calculation not displaying correct value

Tags: java

I wrote a simple program that receives several inputs and it does a future investment calculation.

However, for some reason, when I enter the following values:
investment = 1
interest = 5
year = 1

I get `Your future value is 65.34496113081846` when it should be 1.05.

```
import java.util.*;

public class futurevalue
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This program will calculate your future investment value"); 

    System.out.println("Enter investment amount: ");
    double investment = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter annual interest amount: ");
    double interest = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number of years: ");
    int year = sc.nextInt();


    double futureValue = investment * (Math.pow(1 + interest, year*12));

    System.out.println("Your future value is " + futureValue);


  }
}
```

Found my mistake. I divided my interest twice.

Comment: Are you sure your monthly interest shouldn't be divided by 100 ?

Comment: Your interest is 500%. Try 5%, or 0.05.

Comment: Damn, I'm such an idiot. Thanks Jeff and dystroy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should divide your interest by 100.

Comment: I still think it won't give 1.05. Compound interest.

Comment: @MarkByers It does give (approximately) 1.05, but I agree with you that that looks like the wrong way to calculate monthly interest from an APR

Answer (score 1):

How is the interest rate being entered? Should you not divide it by 100 before adding 1 inside Math.pow?

Example: Monthly interest = 1%, if you enter 1, your Math.pow would be Math.pow(1+1, year*12) which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your main error is not dividing by 100 to convert from percents to proportion, but you have another error:

If you have an APR of 5% the formula you need to use to calculate a compounding monthly interest isn't `5%/12`, it's

```
(0.05+1)^(1/12)-1
```

And then the return for that investment ends up being:

```
1 * ( (0.05+1)^(1/12)-1 +1 )^(1 * 12) =
1 * ( (0.05+1)^(1/12) )^(12) =
1 * ( 0.05+1 ) = 1.05
```

exactly.